# How to read back the bytes file in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

In Python, I have saved a model as joblib file, and I read the joblib as bytes using

```
bytes_data = open('model.joblib','rb').read()
```

Then I convert to base64 using below code and store in a database

```
import base64
base64_data = base64.b64encode(bytes_data)
```

Later I load the base64_data from database and decode back to binary

```
loaded_binary = base64.b64decode(base64_data)
```

Now I am writing the binary file back

```
bytes_load = open(loaded_binary,'wb').write()
```

Here I am getting Error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-28-1d2986913b15>", line 1, in <module>
    bytes_load = open(loaded_binary,'wb').write()

UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x80 in position 0: invalid start byte
```

reading and writing binary doesn't allowing the encoding arguments, I need to get back the same model.

Comment: `open(..., 'wb').write(...)`…?

Comment: I have tried that, but getting error as "UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x80 in position 0: invalid start byte"

Comment: Are you sure you're setting the `b` mode when writing the file? Show your code and the full error message, including stack trace.

Comment: I have edited the question with errors, Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You pass decoded binary file content as file name into open function. I guess instead of

```
bytes_load = open(loaded_binary,'wb').write()
```

You need:

```
bytes_load = open('somefilename', 'wb').write(loaded_binary)
```

Comment: Thanks @Konstantin, bad me, didn't realize, Worked